# How to make a generic method that take a generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to write the following method

```
private void Foo<T, TItem>(T<TItem> param1)
```

Where T must be a generic type that takes TItem as its generic info.

Call example would be like:

```
private void Main()
{
    List<int> ints = new List<int>();
    Foo<List, int>(ints);    
}
```

**Edit:**
In my case I would only need to for collections.
The actual use case is that I wanted to write a method that adds something to a ICollection sadly the `ICollection` doesn't have an `.Add` method only the `ICollection<T>` has it.

I cannot change the method to:

```
private Foo<T>(ICollection<T>)
```

since with that I am losing the information what type the actual list is, which is more important to me than what type the items within the list.

so the above idea was born, which didn't work.

Comment: I don't think that's possible given that `List` always expects a generic parameter.

Comment: I don't think you can make that constraint. What about having T be a generic type which implements IInterface<T> where T derives from TItem?

Comment: I don't really understand how `Foo` would require `T` and `TItem` to be related in the described way; could you give a more specific example?

Comment: What is T? Only collection types or something else? Can you provide more examples how you want to use the code?

Comment: `IList` has an Add method. Can that be used instead?

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey - no since the method should also work with hashsets, and hashset doesn't have IList implemented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you need that for collections only, you could describe a method like this:

```
private void Foo<T, TItem>(T param1)
    where T: ICollection<TItem>
{
}
```

However in this case you need to provide specific generic type (`List<int>`) as first generic parameter, you can't use just `List`:

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
Foo<List<int>, int>(ints);
```

Comment: ``IEnumerable<TItem>`` ??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Since `ICollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` you could use one or the other, that depends on requirements

Comment: This solution seems to work, but it kinda stinks that I have to specify the generic type information, is there maybe some way around it?

Comment: @RandRandom Unfortunatelly I can't think of a way to cheat generics in this case

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help:

Create a base class and derived class.

```
public class Item
{

}

public class Item<T> : Item
{
    T Value;

    public Item(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

You can then use it how you want to:

```
public class SomewhereElse
{
    public void Main()
    {
        List<Item> itemCollection = new List<Item>();
        itemCollection.Add(new Item<int>(15));
        itemCollection.Add(new Item<string>("text"));
        itemCollection.Add(new Item<Type>(typeof(Image)));
        itemCollection.Add(new Item<Exception>(new StackOverflowException()));
        itemCollection.Add(new Item<FormWindowState>(FormWindowState.Maximized));
        // You get the point..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you are caught in a mind trap. There is probably a better way to solve whatever it is you are trying to do.

Anyway, try using a `Dictionary`. You don't need to actually write a method.

```
int number = 15;
double dub = 15.5;
Button button = new Button();

Dictionary<object, Type> typeGlossary = new Dictionary<object, Type>();
typeGlossary.Add(number, typeof(int));
typeGlossary.Add(dub, typeof(double));
typeGlossary.Add(button, typeof(Button));
```

Eventually, your forward raging code-injected brain will give up trying to un-strong the strongly typed system of C#. We all do it at some point.